# check all Condition class in jquery

Tags: jquery

i use this function for check validating class .

```
<script>
function check_form()
{
if ( !$(".validating").val() )
{
$(".validating").css("background-color","yellow");
}
else
$(".validating").css("background-color","#fff");
}
</script>
```

and html code

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="txt1" class="validating">
<input type="text" name="txt1" class="validating">
<input type="submit" onclick="check_form()" >
</form>
```

onclick fisrt work fine and bg yellow . but when first input (txt1) fill text page refresh???

but when second input (txt2) fill and first empty yet work right .

i think function check only first input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all the inputs with that class like this:

```
function check_form() {
    $(".validating").each(function () {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        } else $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
    });
}
```